# Strange CSS behavior on on Iphone

Tags: css, mobile, safari, mobile-safari

I have an animation on my home page where my logo spins into place. On desktop and both the Chrome and Firefox mobile simulators it works fine but on an actual phone it makes an additional 90deg rotation. Here are screenshots from firefox mobile view and my iphone

This is correct
[image]

This is incorrect (iphone)
[image]

and the code

```
@keyframes spin { 100% { transform:rotate(720deg); } }
@keyframes size { 
  0% { opacity: 0; transform: scale(0); }                                             
  30% { opacity: 0; transform: scale(0); }                                             
  100% { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1); } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue wasn't code related, but rather the Apple browser was reading the image metadata in a particular rotation. The fix was to create a new logo in the correct orientation from the start and now it works fine. I think I may have rotated that last image in the apple viewer after it was exported from Inkscape.

So the desktop browser was seeing the image as is was after rotation and the mobile browser (Apple in this case) was reading the image data and not taking into account the fact that it was rotated.